# How do I read POST response using angularjs?

Tags: php, angularjs, node.js, post, response

I am working on payment gateway integration. Following is my code which fires the request.

```
<form name="ecom" action="https://www.test.com/test/secure/Payment.jsp" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="requestparameter" value="xxxxxxxxxxx" />
<input type="hidden" name="billingDtls" value="xxxxxxxyyyyyzxxx" />
<input type="hidden" name="shippingDtls" value="xxxxxxxnnnnn" />
<input type="hidden" name = "merchantId" value ="201xxxxxx22">
</form>
```

The third party returns response and the control is redirected to success page. How do I read the response in angularjs? I am using `angularjs` as frontend while `nodejs` as backend. Earlier I had used `PHP` as backend and `jquery or javascript` as frontend and accessed the response using `$_POST['resp']`.

Now I need to access the response in angularjs. Is there any `$_POST["responseparams"]` equivalent in `angularjs`?

Comment: POST is a request, not a response.  Values are posted to server-side code.  It's not really clear what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @David, the third party redirects on success page with some response, how to I read the response in angularjs?

Comment: Please post your question more clearly. What code do you have. What are you trying to do

Comment: @MissChetanGawai: You don't read a response in JavaScript.  The third party is posting to the *server*.  Whatever the server renders to the page will contain JavaScript code.  If there are server-side values that need to be known in that resulting page, just emit them to the page when rendering it.

Comment: @Arno_Geismar, please go through the edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any $_POST["responseparams"] equivalent in angularjs?

No, because that's server-side code and AngularJS is client-side code.  The third-party is posting to the *server*, not to the user's *browser*.

> I am using angularjs as frontend while nodejs as backend.

Then your NodeJS code will be reading the POST values.  I don't know enough about NodeJS to show a concrete example, but I assume it has the ability to render output similar to how PHP/ASP/etc. all do?  That's where you would be sending the values to the client-side code.

> Earlier I had used PHP as backend and jquery or javascript as frontend and accessed the response using $_POST['resp'].

The concept is identical.  In PHP you would read the value with `$_POST['resp']`, perform whatever logic you need to in server-side code (which may be none, other than basic input sanitation to prevent things like XSS attacks), and emit to the client.  For directly emitting a JavaScript value to a page, that might have looked something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var resp = '<?php echo $resp; ?>';
</script>
```

Or perhaps you'd go a step further and separate the client-side code from the values, perhaps storing the data server-side and exposing it via an API which would be consumed by AJAX calls from the client-side code.

Either way, the structure would be the same with NodeJS and AngularJS.  The value is posted to a server-side resource, which in turn responds with a page as output.  That page would contain the JavaScript code that needs to run on the page.  Simply plug in any values you need to from server-side code when rendering that page.